# How to trace fork() inside for loop?

Tags: for-loop, fork, trace

```
int i;
for(i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
    fork();
    printf("H\n");
}
Result 14 times H
```

1)When I try binary tree technique or 2(power)N. I end up with 8 outputs.
2)Also when I take out curly brackets, I end up with 8.

What are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=1
fork -----------------------
"H" (printed)              "H" (printed)
i=2 (next loop)            i=2
fork----------             fork----------       
"H"          "H"           "H"           "H"    
i=3          i=3           i=3           i=3
fork----     fork----      fork----      fork----     
"H"    "H"   "H"    "H"    "H"    "H"    "H"    "H"
```

2+4+8 = 14 prints of "H"

with out the curly brackets you only get the printf after the loop, that's the bottom row,
 8 prints of "H"